# List effective values of all existing mount options for a partition?

Tags: linux, mount

The `mount` command and `cat /proc/mounts` only list those mount options that have values different than default.

How can I obtain (for a given mounted partition) an **exhaustive** list of the applied values of **all** the mount options that the partition's filesystem defines? Think "computed style" but for a mounted partition rather than a HTML element ;)

Comment: On which version of which operating system?

Comment: Does this help: `sudo tune2fs -l <device>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic Linux mount interface does not provide any more information about this.

The default generic mount options are `rw,suid,dev,exec,async`.  (I looked in `man mount` for the definition of `defaults`, and removed anything that was not a kernel mount flag).

To take one popular example, the `ext4` filesystem does not show the full list of default `ext4` options in `/proc/mounts`.  You should be able to work out *most* of the defaults just from reading the "Mount options" sections in `man ext4`.  This is a lot of reading :-).  It also says it could vary depending on the kernel version.  For the ones it does not specify, it appears that:

- `acl` is enabled by default, if the kernel was built with support for it (CONFIG_EXT4_FS_POSIX_ACL=y).
- `delalloc` is enabled by default for filesystems created as `ext4`.
- `auto_da_alloc` is enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with **EXT4**. More complete list of applied mounting options:

```
cat /proc/fs/ext4/sda1/options
```

Full list of available mounting options:

https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/ext4.html

And also directly look at the kernel source code:
**`./linux/fs/ext4/`**

Comment: Nice. `/proc/fs/<fs>/<bdev>/options` doesn't seem to be available for btrfs at least though (and one btrfs FS can be backed by more than one block device, not sure how that would be reflected there if it was supported; not to mention that like on ZFS, different subvols can have different mount options).

Comment: You could also mention `/proc/self/mountinfo` that sometimes has more information than `/proc/mounts`. See also `findmnt --output-all -J`